# IO timeout value for Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, timeout, io

If a disk has some problems, the disk driver usually retries it. For example, sometimes Linux SCSI driver will get BUSY status from SCSI drives  and resend the IO. The upper layers (e.g., FS) will wait until:
1. The disk driver can't handle the IO error and directly report error.
2. The disk driver still retries but timeout occurs.

My question is that what's the timeout value in Windows and Linux platforms? For example, if I invoke "write" to send some data to disk synchronously, how long will the system call return if it can't really write data?

Thanks!

Comment: This might get better answers if you make it specific to one OS or the other. Maybe split it into two questions one for Linux and one for Windows? I doubt that many Linux experts will also have expert Windows knowledge.

Comment: Not just specific to the OS, but specific to the driver itself.

Comment: ... and specific to the type of I/O. But still, for IRPs in Windows there is a hard limit, too. That much I remember.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian notes, it's driver dependent.  The write returns when the driver gives up.  How and why the driver gives up is driver and device dependent.  There is no timeout, per se, like reads often have.

Comment: Not entirely, but almost. On Windows, to my knowledge, pending IRPs, if not marked as pending, will be cancelled by the I/O manager after some time. Still +1. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can get the IO timeout value from each block device by reading the value on :

/sys/block/**mydevice**/device/timeout

By default, the value is 60s.

Comment: note that you can change the timeout by writing a new value to that file as well.

Comment: The file doesn't exist for nvme device.